Stacked graph with dual line graph
`
#packages required
library("readxl")
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
library("reshape")  
library("scales")

# Adding a column with the sum of x and y

#>    x chromosome plasmid gc(%)  cds
#> 1  1998  1        0     50.8   4298 
#> 2  2001  0        1     50.4   4132
#> 3  2002  1        1     51.2   3954
#> 4  2006  2        2     50.2   4200

years_data <- read_excel("D:/menuscript/forgraph.xlsx", sheet = "data")
years_data <- as.data.frame(years_data)
years_data_long <- melt(years_data, id.vars = "Year")
years_data_long <- years_data_long[years_data_long$variable %in% c("chromosome", "plasmid","gc","cds"), ]
ggplot(years_data_long, aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = variable)) +`
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Count", fill = "Type") +
  ggtitle("Counts by Year") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = years_data$Year)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0, hjust=0))


###################################################`
I got this but i need gc and cds as line graph and chromosome and plasmid as stacked
Like this image in need but dual line . one line representing gc another representing cds 

It would be helpful if you could include your data or fake data in your question so we can reproduce your results.
To add lines to your bar chart, you should only specify aes(x) in the ggplot() function. Then specify the aes(y) in each geom_** step.
I've adjusted your code below to accommodate this. There is now an aes(y =) in each geom argument.
years_data <- read_excel("D:/menuscript/forgraph.xlsx", sheet = "data")
years_data <- as.data.frame(years_data)
years_data_long <- melt(years_data, id.vars = "Year")
years_data_long <- years_data_long[years_data_long$variable %in% c("chromosome", "plasmid","gc","cds"), ]
ggplot(years_data_long, aes(x = Year) +`
  geom_bar(aes(y = value, fill = variable), stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
 geom_line(aes(y = cds)) +
 geom_line(aes(y = gc)) + 
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Count", fill = "Type") +
  ggtitle("Counts by Year") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = years_data$Year)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0, hjust=0))


Additional examples of this live here:
How to implement stacked bar graph with a line chart in R and here ggplot - dual line chart and stacked bar chart on one plot

Thank you it worked but one issue the dates with gap is not filled
